# R: Speed up for loop containing which

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

I have two data frames - one contains a bunch of postcodes and surveys allocated to them (`df1`), the other contains all possible postcodes and the zones within which these are contained (`df2`). I essentially need to remove the postcodes, and allocate each survey to a zone (using the postcodes to cross reference). Currently I estimate my program will take 5hrs. how can I speed this up?

```
for (i in 1:nrows(df1)) {
    index <- which(df2$postcodes == toString(df1$postcodes[i])
    if (length(index)) {
        df1$zone <- toString(df2[index])
    } else {
        df1$zone <- 'UNMATCHED'
    }
}
```

Currently, I've found that running this for 100 postcodes takes about 6 seconds.

I have tried a bunch of things for the past couple of hours with little to no progress, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you familiar with any package such as dplyr or data.table or prefer base R? Also would be great if you posted examples of `df1` and `df2` in a reproducible format (can be copied into a R session)

Comment: sounds like a pretty default use of a (left) join... read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an inner join, which can be achieved with dplyr. And you can drop the `postcodes` column after. Here is a nice cheat sheet: http://stat545.com/bit001_dplyr-cheatsheet.html

> *inner_join(x, y): Return all rows from x where there are matching values in y, and all columns from x and y. If there are multiple
>   matches between x and y, all combination of the matches are returned.
>   This is a mutating join.*

Comment: The link is a very smooth intro to joins